# Why would a textbox border be light and then disappear when text fills it?

Tags: wpf, rendering

When our application is viewed on two particular machines, one is **Vista** and one **XP**, we have the effect on some text boxes, when focused, the left and right borders are "**soft**", and when you type past the right border, it **disappears** altogether, like this:

[image]

On **all other** machines that we tested it looks fine, however.

For all its worth, below is the style we have on the TextBox, although when I make a sample WPF application and apply this style to a TextBox, I don't get the same problem on the two problem machines, so it seems some other **combination** of settings/styles in our application which causes this.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#7F9DB9" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
</Style>
```

**Has anyone experienced this rendering/alias problem in WPF and/or solved it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark: is `SnapsToDevicePixels` set to `true` for the `Border` in the `TextBox`? You can use [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) to check.

Comment: Thanks, snoop did the trick (an amazing tool, I can recommend the CTRL-SHIFT-click-on-element feature), problem was a midwidth was on the grid and so the textbox was smaller than the wrapping grid column and hence the text was going "under" the margin area on the right.